# Problems with creating name and regularly accessing view-only wallet for cold storage

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, viewkey, cold-storage

Thanks for taking the time to help me out.  I've created a couple view-only wallets using https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/user-guides/view_only , and have been coming across some problems:

1) When I actually do create the wallet that has my cold wallet address associated with it, it saves the wallet name as "WalletAddress:ViewKey:NameIWantToGiveIt", instead of just "NameIWantToGiveIt".

2) When I go to refresh the wallet, it works perfectly; but the problem is, is when I save it by typing "save" and/or "exit" it will save,  but then I'll shut it down and turn it back on the next day without being able to access my wallet.  It's not a problem with the password, it's that it says that it won't recognize the name and will generate a new one for me even though I put "WalletAddress:ViewKey:NameIWantToGiveIt" for the name.

3) I don't know if this part is mostly my fault; but sometimes in the past when I created the wallet providing the address and viewkey (it would ask me me again for it after I did   –generate-from-view-key yourAddress:yourViewKey:nameOfTheViewOnlyWallet) the address associated with the wallet would completely change regardless, as if generating another wallet for itself.

If you guys could give me some pointers as to what I might be doing wrong, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I just looked into this, and it seems the method for generating from an address and view key has changed. I am using simplewallet from v0.9.4 and can create a view-only wallet, save it, and then open it again using the following command  (I am showing the Monero Developer's donation address and view key here):

```
simplewallet --generate-from-view-key monerodevaddr.bin --password xxxx
```

Simplewallet then prompts you for the address

```
Standard address: 44AFFq5kSiGBoZ4NMDwYtN18obc8AemS33DBLWs3H7otXft3XjrpDtQGv7SqSsaBYBb98uNbr2VBBEt7f2wfn3RVGQBEP3A
```

followed by the view key

```
View key: f359631075708155cc3d92a32b75a7d02a5dcf27756707b47a2b31b21c389501
```

I then can save and exit

```
exit
```

and reopen the wallet

```
simplewallet --wallet-file monerodevaddr.bin --password xxxx
```

---

**Note:** I did not test this method with `refresh` after creating the wallet because 1) I don't think that should matter as to whether things are working and 2) the Monero Developer's donation address has a ton of inputs and refreshing would take a long time.

**Note 2:** This change in creation method seems to have been made sometime between v0.9.1 and v0.9.4, and it is possible that it will change again in the next version (v0.10). As far as I am aware, I do not think the simple command you said above works anymore...

Comment: Thank you so much! Will try to use this when I get home and will get back to you

Comment: Ok I just tried it out and sorry for the poor formatting because I'm typing this on my phone because for some reason I can't log on through my laptop... Anyways.. First it seems I have to start with the "./simplewallet" command first along with the rest of your first command; and when I typed a password it would take my first few characters along with "--password XXXXX".  Could this be becaus there is a space in between the password command and password? Also it asked me first after I entered that command what block height I wanted to start at, I typed 0 and it basically shut everything down

Comment: Yeah, "./simplewallet" might make sense depending on how it is installed. the "./" means "use the simplewallet executable located in the current directory".


||| and when I typed a password it would take my first few characters along with "--password XXXXX" |||


I don't understand what you're saying. Can you write out your entire command line input and the show what that does for file name and password generation?  You could always just need to omit "--password xxxx" and set the password when it prompts you.

Comment: simplewallet is new to me, thanks for the info!